# Using a variable that was set in a previous include

Tags: craft3, include, blocks

By base.html:

```
{% block searchLogic %}                                
{% endblock %}                

{% block meetingDisplay %}
{% endblock %}
```

My index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block searchLogic %}
{% include 'logic/anonVisitor.logic' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block meetingDisplay %}
Some html code
{% for meeting in meetings %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

My anonVisitor.logic file:

```
{# More code that works, I just removed it for clarity #}
{% set meetings = craft.entries.section('meetings').address(params).limit(25).order('distance').find() %}
```

I try to use the variable meetings in the block "meetingDisplay" in the index.html file. For some reason the variable "meetings" is no longer available.

I am trying to seperate my logic blocks and my html blocks into separate files for manageability and reuse.

All this logic worked before I broke the code and html using the extends and includes.

Is there a way to make variables set in an include be available in a block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're running into is Twig scoping rules, which is discussed at length in the article [Twig Processing Order & Scope](https://nystudio107.com/blog/twig-processing-order-and-scope)

The TL;DR is that a variable is only available in the context in which it is defined. Since you're setting the `meetings` variable in a file you included, that variable exists only in the context of the `anonVisitor.logic` file.

Additionally, variables defined in a parent context are available to any child templates that are included, but you can't *change* the values in the child templates, because you're given a copy of the context that goes away when the child templates are done rendering.

What you can do is leverage `extends` and `embed`, because templates that `extends` other templates have the same context as the parent that they `extends`.